# Motherboard ASRock trouble coolers speed

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling

I own an ASRock H470M-ITX/ac motherboard and am having trouble with it.
 In the aida64 program, I did a stress test on computer systems and found that my computer thinks that the coolers in the computer case are the processor cooler, and the processor cooler is the coolers in the computer case. The connectors are connected correctly. 
I updated UEFI, reset UEFI to factory settings, and updated the drivers (according to the official website and from the disk out of the box upon purchase) and this did not help. 
 I also tried to change the connectors connected to the motherboard in places. (Fans in the body 3-pin, and computer cooler 4-pin). After that, when you start the computer, the CPU cooler started to turn at the maximum speed, which is very strange.

After that, in the aida64 program (with stress test) the computer began (with increasing CPU temperature) to increase the CPU cooler speed. At the same time, it was shown in the program that this increased the speed of rotation of fans in the body.

Earlier (before UEFI upgrade, reset to UEFI factory settings, switching of seats connectors) AIDA64 showed that it increases the speed of rotation of the processor cooler, and in fact, increased the speed of fan rotation in the body.

Honestly, I don't know what time the changes occurred, but the computer behaves very strange

My system config:

- Motherboard: ASRock H470M-itx/ac
- Prosessor: Intel I5 10400 (graphics included)
- Processor cooler: ID-cooling SE223-basic
- Power: Chieftec powerup 650w GPX 650fx
- Case: Fractal Design define Nano s window
- Case coolers: Stock from factory (fractal design R3 120mm & 140mm)
- SSDs: NVME SSD SAMSUNG 980 1Tb, NVME SSD Silicon Power SP512GBP34A80M28, and SATA SSD HKDIVISION C100 240gb

I think this might be a software error from the factory.
Downloaded drivers from the link: https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H470M-ITXac/#BIOS

Comment: Hi. What is your precise question? Imagine that you ask me/us the question in person, as written in the title field when you ask a new question on this website.

Comment: Have you emailed AsRock tech support, as that would generally be the recommended route since there's nothing anyone can suggest to do since fans are controlled by the BIOS/UEFI firmware, which is an OEM issue.

Comment: @JW0914
Of course, I wrote to support at 4 mail addresses. The link "solving technical problems" on the site is not available, so I had to write to the sales department in 2 cases, but in the other 2 it was the development department. The only people I got a response from were the sales department. This was the most generic answer "specify your problem in more detail."